# How to prove Orbot is working for apps

Tags: tor

I am using Orbot to torify the traffic of a certain app. To be sure I selected the option 'Tor Everything', because I dont need high speed internet on this phone anyway.

Now besides using this browser and checking my ip is there any way is there anyway to prove tor is working for all the other apps aswell ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general way to verify if an unspecific app has been *torifyed*, but you could simulate behavior of https://check.torproject.org/ web service (which essentially looks up HTTP client address in [tor exit node list](https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py) and reports if found or not) using general purpose utilities as follows:

Launch terminal and telnet to public route server

```
user@android:/ $ telnet route-views.optus.net.au
```

At server prompt issue `show users` command

```
route-views.optus.net.au>sh users
    Line       User       Host(s)              Idle       Location
   2 vty 0                idle                 00:01:32 94.228.44.113
*  3 vty 1                idle                 00:00:00 tor-exit01.baconsvin.org
   4 vty 2                idle                 00:04:46 203.81.71.31
   5 vty 3                idle                 00:00:46 cg.eastlink.ca

  Interface    User               Mode         Idle     Peer Address
```

An asterisk `*` at line `3` (`vty1`) denotes an active line you are using to connect, and location of your line's endpoint (`tor-exit01.baconsvin.org` in this case) clearly marks **tor exit node** (some exit nodes do not have so friendly reverse DNS, so check against known endpoints like your ISP, VPN or look up in tor exit node list).

Thus, you just connected through **tor** (try the same with tor stopped to see the difference) and hence, Orbot's **transparent proxying** feature works for all apps.

Comment: thank you for your answer unfortunately I cant upvote your answer. How would the routing look like if I'd use an additional VPN ? Android->VPN->Tor->Appserver ?

Comment: @flxh, sorry, I can't say for sure without configuring a lab.  Just tested with simple anti-censorship VPN I use and **Tor over VPN** tunneling didn't work. Also, expanded the answer a bit on how to figure out current connection type from location reported by network service.